# Google Apps Script web app response for POST request acts weird

Tags: google-apps-script, curl, google-calendar-api

I'm making a small Apps Script to create a calendar event via POST request.

Here is the code:

```
function doPost(e) {
    const accessKey = 'l056SH7REYsuli**************************************************DIX0e08XvsBAtzA2eSJg';
    let result;
    let params = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
    let event = params.event;
    let calendarId = params.calendarId;
    let token = params.token;
    let method = params.method;
    if(token === accessKey) {
        try {
            eventResult = Calendar.Events.insert(event, calendarId);
            result = { 'Event ID: ' : eventResult.id }
            } catch (err) {
            result = { 
                'Failed with error %s': err.message,
                'Event contents': event
                    }
            }
    } else {
        result = {
            'status': 'Forbidden',
            'statusCode': 403,
            'message': 'You do not have access to this resource.'
        }
    }
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(result))
}
```

It works perfect with Postman:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wjaye.png)

But when I do curl:
curl --location --request POST 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyh7n3YeE-HiNAIA8wi9HAVsaLBUv5ceJu-k7yxL4D8mSm9EXQ4wQc_ctqipFlAR4SqfA/exec' 
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' 
--data-raw '{
"token": "l056SH7REYs**************************************************3IYXeiECDIX0e08XvsBAtzA2eSJg",
"calendarId": "c_9bae2a34a108dd90**************************************5ee00d@group.calendar.google.com",
"event": {
"summary":"TEst from postman",
"description":"Abyrvalg",
"start": {
"date": "2022-11-28"
},
"end": {
"date": "2022-11-28"
},
"colorID": 9
}
}'
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVNfy.png)
I get HTML instead of JSON.

Calendar event is getting created however. But I need the event ID as a result.
Can anyone share an idea, please?

Googling did not give me any results yet, but I'm not stopping.

Comment: About `But when I do curl: enter image description here I get HTML instead of JSON.`, can you provide your tested curl command?

Comment: Hi, I edited the post. This curl is basically copied from postman snippet.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your sample image of https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVNfy.png , can I ask you about the value of the title tag in the HTML? I cannot understand the language. I apologize for this.

Comment: It's a reply from Google Disk saying File was not found.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modified curl command as an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your following tested curl command,

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyh7n3YeE-HiNAIA8wi9HAVsaLBUv5ceJu-k7yxL4D8mSm9EXQ4wQc_ctqipFlAR4SqfA/exec'
--header 'Content-Type: application/json'
--data-raw '{ "token": "l056SH7REYs************3IYXeiECDIX0e08XvsBAtzA2eSJg", "calendarId": "c_9bae2a34a108dd905ee00d@group.calendar.google.com", "event": { "summary":"TEst from postman", "description":"Abyrvalg", "start": { "date": "2022-11-28" }, "end": { "date": "2022-11-28" }, "colorID": 9 } }'
```

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified curl command:

```
curl --location 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyh7n3YeE-HiNAIA8wi9HAVsaLBUv5ceJu-k7yxL4D8mSm9EXQ4wQc_ctqipFlAR4SqfA/exec' \
--data-raw '{ "token": "l056SH7REYs************3IYXeiECDIX0e08XvsBAtzA2eSJg", "calendarId": "c_9bae2a34a108dd905ee00d@group.calendar.google.com", "event": { "summary":"TEst from postman", "description":"Abyrvalg", "start": { "date": "2022-11-28" }, "end": { "date": "2022-11-28" }, "colorID": 9 } }'
```

#### Reference:

- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script (Author: me)](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)

Comment: @Sergei Lavrov Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.